# What is the joint distribution $f_{ZX}$ if $Z=X+Y$ and $X \sim N(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_y,\sigma_y^2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume

$Z=X+Y$, given that $X \sim N(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_y,\sigma_y^2)$ are independent.

I'm interested on computing the joint distribution $f_{ZX}$.

What I think:

Well, I know the distribution of $Z\sim N(\mu_x+\mu_y , \sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2 )$. Also we know the distribution of $X$.

To find the joint I can think of something like findind the joing CDF and then try to do derivatives, though, I suspect this might not be the best way to do it.

I'm thinking on something like:

$F_{ZX} = P(Z \leq z, X \leq x) $

Then, the final expression would be something like $\min(\cdot , \cdot)$ where the dots represent some argument, as I see that to satisfy both conditions I will need the $\min$  operator.

Anybody knows a better way? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(Z,X) = (X+Y, X)$ is obtained from $(X,Y)$ via a *linear transformation* and since $(X,Y)$ has a bivariate Gaussian distribution, so does $(Z, X)$ have a bivariate Gaussian distribution. This is a property (actually a *defining property*) of multivariate Gaussian distributions: linear transformations preserve multivariate Gaussianity.

So, all you need to do is figure out the mean and variance of $Z=X+Y$ (the mean and variance of $X$ are known to you), and then the *covariance* of $Z$ and $X$ and then you can *write down* the distribution of $(Z,X)$ with very little effort.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, it indeed helps. However, as I'm trying to work it out, I'm finding I'm unable to find the COV(Z,X), as I need the correlation coefficient. What am I missing? thanks professor.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it:
I need $E[ZY] = E[(X+Y)Y]$, opening the product: $E[ZY] = E[ XY + Y^2 ]$.
Then, $E[ZY] = E[XY] + E[Y^2] $. The firs them is E[X]E[Y] since they are independent, whereas the second term is second moment of Y.

Comment: @pkenneth81 If you look carefully, you will find that what you need to compute is $E[ZX] = E[x^2+XY] = E[X^2]$ and not $E[ZY] = E[(X+Y)Y] = E[Y^2]$

Comment: Thanks. You are right, for some reason I did change X to Y in my computations in my notebook. But at the end, results are consistent. Thanks for your help.